# WiX Close Minimized Application

Tags: wix, installation

i know of this ancient bug/feature in WiX that cant close minimized to tray applications. Does anyone know if there is a workaround to this. Have been unsuccessfuly searching.

This is how i invoke the close:

```
<util:CloseApplication Id="CloseApp" CloseMessage="yes" Target="App.exe" RebootPrompt="no" ElevatedCloseMessage="yes"/>
```

Comment: It's axiomatic that applications and installers must be designed with each other and the target system in mind. Can you modify the application? If not, what is it?

Comment: My installer is able to close an application minimized to the tray, could it be that the application name is not correct?

Comment: i double checked that. unfortunately not the case. Do you use the same element CloseApplication or are you using smth else?